# Why use supertest instead of unit tests for expressJS?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, supertest

While searching for how to test my node.js software, I came accross many answers advising to use Supertest.

Before using Supertest I was testing my app this way :

```
app.get('/', base_road);
function base_road(req, res) {
   return res.json("Hello world");
}

it("base road", function() {
  base_road(mocked_req, {json: function(data) {
      assert.isEqual(data, "Hello world");
  }});
});
```

I'm not really happy with this way of testing as the mocking can become very hard to read, but I feel like if I use supertest I'll be closer to e2e than unit testing.

Should I use supertest to do unit testing ?
Is my actual way of testing my app correct ?

Comment: Yes, you will but that's the point. If you want to test services and inside-backend functions you would use mocha.

Answer (score 4):

`supertest` is a library used for integration testing, not unit testing and e2e testing.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing#cite_ref-2):

> Integration testing takes as its input modules that have been unit tested, groups them in larger aggregates, applies tests defined in an integration test plan to those aggregates, and delivers as its output the integrated system ready for system testing.

It can be used for API automation testing.

Unit testing and integration testing are not conflicting. For a Node.js express web application, both of them should be written to ensure software quality. They are not substitution relationships, but coexistence and dependency relationships

This is a diagram showing the relationship between these tests:

[image]

Comment: supertest can be used with a remote URL. Then, doesn't it mean it's E2E testing? Because for restful APIs, it's accessing from the end point.